# In R, how to make axis label start closer to the origin (NOT closer to the axis itself)?

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have a barplot where the y-axis label is "Fisher Information Metric". The problem is that this label extends beyond the top end of the y-axis. I want to make the label start from close to the origin (y=0), but can't seem to find anything to do this. Standard tutorials and blogs are full of omd, omi, par, etc. ... but nothing to make the label "slide" closer to the (0,0) point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I agree that it can be difficult to figure out which par parameter to use. I first looked at `?par`, then at `?axis`, then at `?title` and back again to `?par`.) Try this:

```
 barplot ( .... , adj=0.1)
```